# Ejs2 include(variable) not working

Tags: node.js, ejs

Ejs2 docs say it is possible to do:

```
exports.get = function(req, res) {

    res.render('layouts/home', {
        page: '../pages/' + 'home'
    });

};
```

and then within the layouts/home.ejs:

```
<!-- !PAGE CONTENT! -->
    <div>

        <!-- Sidenav/menu -->
        <% include ../partials/sidebar %>

        <!-- Content -->
        <% include(page) %>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <% include ../partials/footer %>
    </div>
```

but it writes:

```
 { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\project\views\layouts\(page).ejs']
      errno: -4058,
      code: 'ENOENT',
      syscall: 'open',
      path: 'D:\\project\\views\\layouts\\(page).ejs' }
```

I installed ejs2. But somehow it does not work. Before this ejs1 worked fine. But i did not have this include(var) functionality.

Comment: Can you link to the doc?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little bit late, but I had the same problem and fixed it by changing:

```
<% include(var) %>
```

to

```
<%- include(var) %>
```

Comment: I will recheck it as I guess I tried this too. Anyway, as a workaround I changed the general architecture and when rendering include not the page layout file, but page folder, where there is an index file, pointing to a very generic layout, which now includes partials and the content of the particular page, which is also in this page folder. So making a new page i only need to change the page content file and nothing else. This layout file is very generic so that i should not have to modify it in case of any restructuring. But thanks for the answer, anyway.